# How do I use include in an embedded xsd referencing another embedded xsd?

Tags: c#, xsd, embedded-resource

Inside my web application, I'm validating Xml documents using xsd files as embedded resources, and that was easy using `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(string)`.

I now need to use the `include` element (I actually need `redefine`, but the error I get is the same, so I'm broadening the scope of the question) inside one of my xsd's referencing another embedded xsd, so what I did was:

- add the following lines to the project's AssemblyInfo.cs

  `[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("TurniArc.xml.schema.ImportOperatoriParametri.xsd", "text/xml", PerformSubstitution = true)]`

  `[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("TurniArc.xml.schema.ProcessiInput.xsd", "text/xml", PerformSubstitution = true)]`
- modified the "include" element inside "ImportOperatoriParametri.xsd" into this:

  ```
  <xs:include schemaLocation="<% = WebResource("TurniArc.xml.schema.ProcessiInput.xsd") %>">
  ```

This technique worked when I had to reference an embedded image from an embedded css. Sadly, here it does not, because the GetManifestResourceStream method throws the exception

```
'<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 3, position 34.
```

It seems like the "PerformSubstition" attribute wasn't set, because it's trying to read the attribute of schemaLocation as a "regular" string.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: +1 Very useful, and important, question.

Comment: It's been a while since this question, but how did you manage to resolve this? (if you remember :)) I'm stuck in the same situation

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've incorrectly nested double-quotes in the attribute. Simplest would be to use single quotes for the outer pair.

```
<xs:include schemaLocation='<% = WebResource("TurniArc.xml.schema.ProcessiInput.xsd") %>'>
```

Comment: You're right, I missed that, but it's still not working with single quotes either inside or outside

Comment: same error message (why do comments have to be at least 15 characters long? :-) I could have answered with a simple yes)